# Multiple OS's, several drives, need a working boot manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader

Okay,  so I have several drives with various operating systems on various partitions.
the main drive is a 200GB sliced into a primary for Ubuntu a swap and some storage. the other drives 2x350GB are similarly chopped up, on the 200GB boot drive, it loads to a boot manager and lists ubuntu and two instances of win 7 (one from the 2nd drive and one on the 3rd drive). There is also a Windows XP partition, which is not displayed in the boot manager.

What I need is a boot on the 200gb with a boot manager that will allow me to select any of the available operating systems by selecting either the name or the partition

sda1 ext4
sda2 extended
sda5 swap
sda3 fat32

sdb and sdc have XP, 7 and soon 8 and some other OS variants.  I simply want to be able to tell the boot manager which partition to boot from,  just getting a blinking cursor when I select windows from the boot manager, even tho it seems to have detected it during install.

I did not do the "along side" option,  I just created a set of partitions on the first drive for Linux,  the other drives were resident in this machine and booting fine, now with the new linux drive booting first, there is some problem. 
Perhaps there is a better boot manager to use?

Answer (score 0):

for booting use Easybcd software it is free for home user and install it. open it you will see add new entry click on it go to linux tab add entry click and selcet "swap partition" and "GRUB2" in it after that click on edit boot menu select the appropriate timeout option and save setting.

Download here:http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml